# Unable to use Contains in LINQ to Entity VS 2017 my query attached

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, where-clause

my query is,

Here i am trying to get region id where the region name matches,

```
var Rid = db.Regions.Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex("%" + Search + "%", p.RegionName) > 0).Select(p => p.RegionId).ToList();
```

Change Id's comma separated in string,

```
string joined = string.Join(",", Rid);
```

Trying to get all records related to Id's comma separated in `string joined`

```
var employ = db.Employees.Include(f => f.City).Include(f => f.Region).Where(p=>p.RegionId);
```

Issue is that we dont have contain when i tried use in where clause ??

Hopes for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Linq we have `Any`:

```
var employ = db.Employees.Include(f => f.City)
                         .Include(f => f.Region)
                         .Where(p=> Rid.Any(rid => rid == p.RegionId));
```

or :

```
var employ = db.Employees.Include(f => f.City)
                         .Include(f => f.Region)
                         .Where(p=> Rid.Contains(p.RegionId));
```

Now it will select those employees have the region id in the `Rid` list.

Answer (score 0):

You should map your relationships using virtual properties:

```
public class Employee
{
    ...

    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class Region
{
    ...

    [ForeignKey("RegionId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then you can use it directly in your where statement:

```
var employees = db.Employees
                  .Where(a => a.Region.RegionName.Contains(Search));
```

or

```
var employees = db.Regions
                  .Where(a => a.RegionName.Contains(Search)
                  .SelectMany(a => a.Employees);
```

This way you are sending less data to do your query, think of the situation where have 100 region ids selected. Also you are doing 1 query instead of 2.

Comment: the query would be expensive matching string instead of the indexed column

Comment: You would have to test this to be sure this isn't optimized by linq or if it's not optimized there, could even be faster in query. I have seen this with a very large database (10 million+ records), inner/outer joining everything is cheaper than comparing a lot of indexes. But my main argument for this is the usage of only one line of code and one call to the database.